# How to parse a custom id from within a markdown heading?

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I want to parse a custom id from a markdown heading. For instance,
`#hello-world` from `#this is a heading {#hello-world}`.

This regex I tried does not seem to work:

```js
const regExp=/#{1,6}\s+.*\{(?<id>.*)\}/g
```

Comment: Maybe just `/#[\w-]+/`? Or, `/#\w+(?:-\w+)*/`.

Comment: `/\{(\#[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\}/gm` would achieve your request - [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TVVSq1/1)

Answer (score 1):

To get your match, you could use a capture group

```
{(#{1,6}\w+(?:-\w+)*)}
```

**Explanation**

- `{` Match the opening `{`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `#{1,6}` Match 1-6 times #
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:-\w+)*` Optionally repeat `-` and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `}` Match the closing `}`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eKDPMi/1)

```js
const regex = /{(#{1,6}\w+(?:-\w+)*)}/;
const str = `#this is a heading {#hello-world}`;
const m = str.match(regex);
if (m) console.log(m[1]);
```

Or the bit broader match, with named group `id`

```
{(?<id>#{1,6}[^{}]*)\}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w2fbGL/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
let text = "#hello-world"
let id = text.match(/#{1,6}([\s\WA-z0-9]+)/g).pop()
console.log(`#this is a heading {${id}}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that extracts the heading ID from the first heading in a markdown text, or an empty string if none found:

```js
function getIdFromFirstHeading(str) {
  let m = str.match(/^#{1,6}.*?\{(#[\w\-]+)\}/m);
  return m ? m[1] : '';
}

const text = 'Text before heading\n\n#This is a heading {#hello-world}\n\nText after heading';
console.log(getIdFromFirstHeading(text) || '(no ID found)');
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- start of line (not text, this is because flag `/m` is used)
- `#{1,6}` -- scan over 1 to 6 `#`, e.g. heading start
- `.*?` -- scan over current line, e.g. heading text, non-greedily, until:
- `\{` -- scan over `{`
- `(#[\w\-]+)` -- capture group #1: capture `#` followed by 1+ word chars or dashes
- `\}` -- scan over `}`
  \n

Note: This regex excludes `{#foo-bar}` patterns outside of heading lines.